# Why is my sql query with a subquery so slow even though the subquery performs fast?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

My query is something like:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.thread = threads.id) AS comments
FROM threads
LIMIT 10
```

`comments.thread` is an index, queries like this run fast:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.thread = 'someId'
```

However, my query is extremly slow. It takes 10 seconds times the limit I define. Why?

Comment: *"My query is something like"* ... you need to show us what your query is *actually like*, not something that you believe to be similar.  You may be making an assumption that what you've provided here is similar enough to what you are really doing that it conveys the gist of your query, but that is not necessarily the case.  The query you've shown isn't actually valid SQL.  Show *your* query.  Modify table and column names if needed, but nothing else, please.

Comment: I ran 'something like' your query in 5.6.22, with suitable indexes.  It was well optimized (as deduced from `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`)

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT t.*,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.thread = t.id) AS comments
FROM threads t
LIMIT 10;
```

You want an index on `comments(thread)`.  If your other query runs fast, then I would guess that you already have one.

Perhaps the `LIMIT` and subquery are acting strangely.  Is this version also slow?

```
SELECT t.*,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.thread = t.id) AS comments
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM threads t
      LIMIT 10
     ) t;
```

Comment: Still takes 10 seconds for each row. The problem must be the subquery. For some reason it becomes slow when used in this query.

Comment: @LuisSequeira . . . How many comments do you have on each thread?

Comment: variable, up to several thousand

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I can't think of a case like this where the derived table would help performance.

Comment: Your version needs to write and reread a tmp table; the original does not.

Comment: @RickJames . . . A correlated subquery instead of an aggregation often helps performance.  I don't have MySQL on hand right now to time it, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - True.  But not in this case.  Anyway, I am talking about the "derived" table (after `FROM`), not the "correlated subquery".  I checked it with a small table and `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`

Comment: @RickJames . . . That is generally true.  But working with 10 rows versus all the rows in the table would generally be faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - In _this_ situation, it would do the correlated subquery only 10 times.  If you add an `ORDER BY` -- to make the `LIMIT` predictable -- and it might go through the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner query is a *corelated* subquery, meaning it uses a value from the outer query, so executes *for every row* of the outer query. Maybe MySQL is not so good at optimizing the query.

Try this:

```
SELECT threads.*, count(comments.thread) AS comments
FROM threads
JOIN comments ON comments.thread = threads.id
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5 -- one number here for each column of the threads table
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `JOIN`.  Even so, that would explode the amount of data by `JOINing`, only to implode it by `GROUP BY`.  It will always be slower.  (Feel free to provide an example where I am wrong.)

Comment: @rick yes, join. You could just run it and see if in fact it's faster, instead of making conjecture.